# React - Get Component name from router location path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I am using withRouter like so:

```js
const SubMenu = props => (
  <div className="subMenu">
    <h2>{props.location.pathname}</h2>
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(SubMenu);
```

How can I get the name of the active component instead of the path?

Comment: IIRC it’s impossible to derive any reference to a component (which is a function) from the store because react-router uses the store properly, that is, keeping only serializable data. And a component may even not have a name, e.g., when it’s a default export function. What could be done though is reuse the router configuration as a module and resolve the routes on location, but I’m not sure react-router provides this API. And as a side-note, I have a feeling you’re solving a wrong problem; perhaps knowing the name of the component and using it is a long path, and there is a shorter one.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply and valuable input.  I have easy access to the Components and they are rendered as expected.  But pathname and Component name are completely separate and can be completely different.

Short of a lookup table to match one to the other, or have every component wrapped in a store to update whenever they are active, can I add a property to Route, like <Route path="/login" name="Login Form" />, that would work?  I actually tried that and it doesnt show up on location nor match.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand the problem. Can you provide more code? One more idea I have in mind would be to refer to `this.constructor.name` (see [a Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/815qrn48n2)), but the number of use cases when it's suitable is limited.

Comment: That works beautifully.  Too bad it doesn't work with functional components.
Post the answer and I will accept it.